# Changing SharePoint Site Collection Title

Tags: sharepoint, title, sitecollection

I need to change the title of a site collection in SharePoint (MOSS 2007). I found one post saying it can be done in SharePoint Designer, but I wasn't seeing the specified menus, and haven't been able to find it anywhere else. I'm assuming I can do it programmatically if necessary, but I'd like to think they made it easier than that (silly me).

**UPDATE:** I actually didn't follow your advice entirely. I simply changed the XML file you located the heading in, and that worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I know what you mean now.  You want to change the title for the html page and not the title of a site.  I did a little digging and here's what I found.

The text "Home" comes from this xml file (on my rig):

**C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\App_GlobalResources\wss.en-US.resx**

```
<data name="multipages_homelink_text">
    <value>Home</value>
</data>
```

By default, Sharepoint creates the title text by concatenating "Home - " + site's title.  So if you want to have totally custom text, do the following:

Open this file for edit:

**C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\sts\default.aspx**

Next, replace the sharepoint title with your custom text:

**Before:**

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_homelink_text%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/> - <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

**After:**

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    Your custom text goes here...
</asp:Content>
```

Hope this is what you're looking for!!!

Comment: note that modifying the SiteTemplate default.aspx file is an unsupported customization.  it may get overwritten in subsequent releases/hotfixes/service packs.  the "blessed" way to do this, is to create your own site definition based on an out of the box one (http://tinyurl.com/6uqaez).

Answer (score 0):

When you said changing the "title of a site collection", do you mean the title of the site collection's top-level-site?

If so, non-programmatically, at the the top level site, go: Site Settings > Title, Description, and Icon.

And programmatically, you can new up the SPWeb of the top level site, then set the Title property.

Comment: No, I mean the entire collection. The collection name is displayed on each page. By default it says 'Home - ' on each page before the site name. I want to change the 'Home' portion.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think the best way is to do  it through code. I think barneytron's answer can solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I face the problem that while creating a sub-site I entered wrong name. Then I wanted to change the name of the site in the navigation bar and everywhere else.

I went to that particular sub-site whose name was to be changed. Then site actions > Look and Feel > Title description and icon. Then change the name.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. Open the site in Sharepoint Designer and click rename button which appears on the top menu. Then you can rename it and save and refresh the site.

If its not working try with administrator who have access prievilages.

!!!!!!!!